# How to disable Slide Icon on last page in Flutter Liquid Swipe...?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to disable the slide icon when you reach last page of Liquid Swipe while not looping?

I want to hide it from last page only.

```
final pages = [...];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              LiquidSwipe(
                initialPage: 0,
                slideIconWidget: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, 
               color: Colors.white),
                liquidController: controller,
                positionSlideIcon: 0.7,
                onPageChangeCallback: onPageChangeCallback,
                enableSideReveal: true,
                pages: pages,
                enableLoop: false,
              ),
              Positioned(
               ...
                child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                  ...
                
      }
    
      onPageChangeCallback(int activePageIndex){
        setState(() {
          currentPage = activePageIndex;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement similar logic to;

```
if (lastPage) {
  setState(() { slideIconWidgetBoolean = false });
else {
  setState(() { slideIconWidgetBoolean = true});
}
```

Without the implementation code sample we can not help you much more than that.